# Java. How do I override initial arguments?

Tags: memory, java

I am in a pickle with a java application. When It launches it uses -Xmx 256m and Xss 2m. I need to make it use more ram because it keeps crashing when running out of ram. So I use java -jar application.jar -Xmx 4G.

Nothing happens, it still uses the built in -Xmx 256m

How do I override the initial settings to give this application more ram?

Answer (score 1):

First, use uppercase `X` as `-Xmx` and `-Xss`; `-x` is an error.

Second, put all JVM options, including `-X` and `-D` and so on, BEFORE `-jar jarname` if you use that, or otherwise before the main-class name. Any arguments after the run-jar or main-class are passed to the Java program, not interpreted by the JVM.

PS: I assume/hope you have 64-bit java (and hardware) if you want 4G.

Comment: I have been using an upper case X. I sorry for wrong info in the post.

Comment: So this is what I have now. start java -Xmx 4g -Xss 1G -jar jarname.jar. This doesn't run.

Comment: Invalid maximum heap size.

Comment: @WebMaster each argument must be a single word with no space: -Xmx4G -Xss1G

Comment: it worked thank you.
the -Xss1G does not work on windows :( says failed to allocate. I do have 4 bit java but the dumb thing keeps running java.exe 32 bit. all other java applications on my pc use the 64 bit java. but the question is answered anyway.

Comment: RIP. So i checked the arguments and https://i.gyazo.com/5b2c8fa9efc632161707012792cc95f9.png
It looks like it strait up ignored the -Xmx4G argument.